# Can topology be thought of as the classification of continuous/infinite groups?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

In other words are the studies of things like genus, characteristic classes, or other invariants on continuous groups (more generally, sets) a way of classifying continuous groups? If so, has there been significant effort to unify these classifications as with finite simple groups?

Apologies if the questions are vague or not on topic for the forum, just a curious thought that came to mind.

Comment: Why the restriction to groups? Topology considers lots of other kinds of topological spaces, not just topological groups (although those are quite interesting and important).

Comment: Topology is useful in studying infinite groups (continuous or even totally disconnected), but topology is much broader. You can define topologies abstractly or on sets without any other structure, including a lack of group structure. To your point, look up topological groups. It's a rich, very beautiful field.

Comment: Some topological spaces are groups but certainly not all...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes I didn't mean to unnecessarily restrict it topology over groups, it was mainly for the purpose of analogy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If so, has there been significant effort to unify these classifications as with finite simple groups?

This is a question about which much can be said. Arguably the nicest class of topological groups are the [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), and among those arguably the nicest ones are (depending on taste) the [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group) Lie groups, or the [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra) Lie groups. These have been [completely classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Classification_of_semisimple_Lie_algebras), and the classification generalizes to a classification of objects called [reductive algebraic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group) which can be used to construct the infinite families of finite simple groups; this classification both inspired and predated (by decades, I think) the (infinite families in the) classification of finite simple groups itself.

Comment: A classification of arbitrary topological spaces is quite hopeless but if we ask for a classification up to (weak) homotopy equivalence then in some sense it is possible to reduce (much of) the classification to some group-theoretic and cohomological data, using what are called Postnikov towers: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Postnikov+system

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of Lie groups but wasn't aware they had been classified as described in your links. Thank you for the info!